# Can't use Symfony VarDumper - Attempted to call function "dump" from namespace

Tags: symfony, symfony4, orocrm, orocommerce

### Context

I'm currently working on an OroPlatform project (4.1.10) and I can't use the Symfony `dump` function in my controllers.

[image]

### Issue

I've seen on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/oro/platform#4.1.10) that OroPlatform 4.1.10 has the `symfony/symfony` dependency which contains `symfony/var-dumper: v4.4.13` and when I've tried to install it, I've got the following error message : `Package symfony/var-dumper is not installed`

Comment: And if you try to install by yourself : `composer require --dev symfony/var-dumper` ?
Caution, it's a dev dependency, are you on "dev" mode ?

Comment: As I said in my question, I've already tried to install it manually but it was a non-sense due to the fact that `symfony/var-dumper` is an OroPlatform dependency.
And yeah, I'm on `dev mode`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To register the dump function, you have to edit `src\AppKernel::registerBundles()` method to add there

```
$bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
```

inside `if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {` statement

Comment: Ok thanks! 
I could have use the following command line to understand that the DebugBundle was not registered : `php bin/console debug:container --parameter=kernel.bundles --format=json`

Comment: I thought it was is adding automatically (in Symfony it is). Is it specified to OroPlatform (i'm discovering this tool) ?

Comment: It indeed can be added automatically. We will fix it in further versions. Thank you for the suggestion.